# cosmos bulk read items query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to make bulk query in cosmos db ?

I have a list of item_ids, is it possible to get output in one query? currently I am using loop which takes lot of time, because iIhave 5K to 20K IDs in one list, to speed up process time, any other solution can we use instead of using threads?

Example code that is using loop:

```
def read_item(self):
         for item_id in self.ids():
            response = self.container.read_item(item=item_id, partition_key=item_id)
```

Cloud: Azure
DB: Cosmos DB
API: SQL
Lang: Python 3.x

Comment: hi @sagar, where are you executing code azure data bricks or vs code

Comment: @BhanunagasaiVamsi VM and container (pod)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.query_items()` method to return all the items with the specified IDs:

```py
import json

def read_item(self):
    id_list_str = json.dumps(self.ids())
    response = self.container.query_items(
        f"SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS({id_list_str}, c.id)",
        enable_cross_partition_query=True
    )
```

Comment: FWIW, the query_items approach seems much faster than looping over read_item, even when doing the latter with 50-100 threads.